# Is there someway to access the windows recent folder with rust?

Tags: windows, rust, permissions

1. Try to write a rust script to remove some recent opened files on windows.
2. Be aware that they are in "C:\Users\xx\Recent" folder.
3. Be able to see them with Win+R then typing recent jumping to the recent folder.
4. Try directly access to the folder with this code.
5. Failed with error Os { code: 5, kind: PermissionDenied }.

```rust
use dirs::home_dir;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let user_folder = home_dir().unwrap();

    let recent_folder = user_folder.join("Recent");

    let recent_folder_contents = fs::read_dir(recent_folder.to_str().unwrap()).unwrap();

    println!("{}", recent_folder.display());
    
    for path in recent_folder_contents {
        println!("{}", path.unwrap().path().display())
    }
}
```

Then i want to know

1. Is there some way to get permissions to access the recent folder?

   I have checked the windows-permission crate, but seems not help.
2. Did know that there's an api called **SHAddToRecentDocs**, which can add one or clear all recent files. Sadly not meet my requirements.

   So is there any api can directly get the recent files? Or to enable/disable the option **show recently used files in quick access**.

   Have searched the windows-rs crate but find nothing with keywords **recent** and **shared**
3. If using c#, seems to be easy with this code and without permission problem, not sure how to do this with rust.

```cs
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(
                          System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                              Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent))
```

Comment: `C:\Users\xx\Recent` is an NTFS junction, it points to the true path:  `C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` - this path is what the C# code is returning.  The `SHGetFolderPath()` win32 API can return the resolved path.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for your help! I did get the right path of Recent using **SHGetKnownFolderPath** since **SHGetFolderPath** been deprecated. Find they been some xxx.automaticDestinations-ms file. I have to figure some way to decode them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @AlexK.'s help. Now is the working code.

```rust
// cargo.toml
[dependencies]
walkdir = "2"
winsafe = { version = "0.0.11", features = [ "shell" ] }


// main.rs
use walkdir::WalkDir;
use winsafe::{co, SHGetKnownFolderPath};

fn main() {
    let docs_folder = SHGetKnownFolderPath(
        &co::KNOWNFOLDERID::Recent,
        co::KF::DEFAULT,
        None,
    ).unwrap();

    println!("Recent Folder Path: {}", docs_folder);
    
    for path in WalkDir::new(docs_folder) {
        println!("{}", path.unwrap().path().display())
    }
}
```

The recent files will be shown as xxx.automaticDestinations-ms or xxx.customDestinations-ms.

Still have some works to figure them out.

Comment: Just a heads up: WinSafe now has the [`path::dir_walk`](https://rodrigocfd.github.io/winsafe/winsafe/path/fn.dir_walk.html) function, so no need to use the walkdir crate anymore.